# How do I prevent orphans when deleting a record from CloudKit?

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud, cloudkit

The CloudKit WWDC videos recommend implementing sync like this:

- Track local changes
- Send changes to the server
- Resolve conflicts
- Fetch server changes with CKFetchRecordChangesOperation
- Apply server changes
- Save server change token

I'm following this pattern in my app, but I'm running into a problem with deletion and parent-child relationships.

Let's say we have a list of books that are split up into categories. Every book has to belong to exactly one category.

I start with data like this:

```
SERVER
Thrillers: "Look Out!", "Secret Spy"
Non-Fiction: "Sailing the Seas", "Gardening Adventures"
Computer Programming: <empty>
```

As you can see, the final category is empty. Let's say I have two devices with exact copies of this data.

Now, on Device 1, the user adds a book `CloudKit Sync` to "Computer Programming":

```
DEVICE 1
Thrillers: "Look Out!", "Secret Spy"
Non-Fiction: "Sailing the Seas", "Gardening Adventures"
Computer Programming: "CloudKit Sync"
```

But on Device 2, the user completely deletes the "Computer Programming" category (it's empty, so this is fine from Device 2's point-of-view):

```
DEVICE 2
Thrillers: "Look Out!", "Secret Spy"
Non-Fiction: "Sailing the Seas", "Gardening Adventures"
```

Device 1 syncs first, so it creates a new `Book` entry with its `parent` field set to `Computer Programming`.

But now Device 2 starts its sync process. It applies its changes to the server, so it deletes the `CKRecord` corresponding to "Computer Programming". This is consistent with Device 2's worldview, where the category is empty and can be deleted.

However, when it deletes this category from the server, this doesn't make sense with respect to the worldview of Device 1 and the server itself. There's now an orphan book called `CloudKit Sync` that has a dangling pointer to its parent.

If I'm following Apple's recommendations from WWDC, how do I avoid this scenario? Depending on the order of the sync, I can easily arrive at an inconsistent state with an orphaned book and an invalid parent reference.

What I'd like to happen is for the `Delete` command from Device 2 to return an error telling me I'm going to orphan a book and prevent the action from occurring at all, so I can take some action to fix the situation.

Is that possible? Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the behavior you want for Device 2 is possible. I see three aspects of cloudkit that will come into play in your scenario. Let's look at those first, then how they might be used in your scenario.

First, assuming that both (or all) devices have subscribed to changes to the appropriate records, each device would be notified that someone else added or removed something. The device receiving the alert would then have the opportunity to decide what to do about it. (remove it from it's local view, replace it on the server, etc)

Second, you can set the behavior for handling conflicts using the `savePolicy` on the `CKModifyRecordOperation`. You can specify whether the last change should overwrite older records, throw an error, etc. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecordsavepolicy?language=objc for the three options. (I've only used this in the context of two users modifying a common record, but a deletion after another user updated the record should then throw a `server record changed` error).

Third, assuming you've configured the aforementioned `savePolicy`, is the server change token itself.  I find it easiest to envision the change token as just a last-modified timestamp. "My copy of this record was last modified at 10:42pm" kind of thing. Depending on the overwrite options you've selected in the aforementioned `savePolicy`, the device will receive an NSError `Server Record Changed` alerting you that the version on the server is from, say, 10:56pm, and that your local version may no longer be valid.

The `userInfo` in the resulting NSError includes 3 versions of the record in question: the current version on the server, the version you tried to submit, and the common ancestor version. The guides from Apple say it's up to the developer to decide what how to merge this information. But in theory, you'd be able to diff the changes, decide which you want to keep, and then submit a new operation.

Regarding your specific scenario: Assuming you fully authorize and trust both dev1 and dev2 to delete records, then I would subscribe to creation and deletion events, and set the `savePolicy` to throw an error when attempting a conflicting change.  In this case, Device 1 would add the record and Device 2 would receive the notification of the new record. If Device 2 simply attempts to delete the old record, it should fail with a `server record changed` error, which you could display to the user as

> "Someone else modified this record, do you really want to delete it
>   (y/n)."

Device 2 would have to refresh the record (and receive the new record change token) before proceeding. After that, if Device 2 still wants to delete the new record, it could, but then Device 1 would be notified of the change via the aforementioned subscription. Device 1 would then download the new record to (or in this case remove the old record from) its local view. The subscription notification could alert user 1:

> "Your record Foo was just deleted by Bar"

This will work even if the events happen practically simultaneously, because one of the changes will be applied on the server first and the other device's token will immediately become out-of-date. So, if Device 2 managed to delete the record first, Device 1's attempt to modify the record will fail with `server record changed` because Device 1's change token is now out of date. Device 1's error handler would have to decide whether to honor the deletion or to proceed with creating a new record based on your business rules. Maybe ask user 1 with something like:

> "Computer Programming" has been removed from the server. Do you want to recreate
>   it?

At this point, user1 can send flame emails demanding other users stop deleting their newly created records, and user2 can demand that people stop recreating the records they just "cleaned up." :)

You could get a lot more complicated, maybe giving device 1 precedence over device 2, such that when device 1 is notified that the record is deleted, then device 1 re-writes the record to the server. If you have multiple users with deletion rights, you could determine an order of precedence and build out the appropriate error/notification handlers. However, this seems excruciating complicated and error prone. Loops that auto respond (create, delete, create, delete, create, delete) could occur. I include it only as a hypothetical example, not a recommendation!

Lastly, as a different example, my app has a different scenario. The records in my case are gaming sessions. All players need read access to the session data, but only the originator is given the option to delete the record altogether. So, you might consider whether you really authorize multiple users to delete shared records or not.